# Prove that Cantor function has zero derivative almost everywhere .

Tags: real-analysis

Is it sufficient to explain that the Cantor set has measure 0. So we consider only complement of Cantor set. Since complement of Cantor set is constant on some intervals, we can say that the derivative is $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The complement of the Cantor set is the union of disjoint open intervals on which the Cantor function is a constant. This implies that this function has derivative $0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: If i write this in my exam, is this considered as a rigorous answer ? (provided I did prove cantor function is constant at complement of Cantor set and measure of cantor set is zero )

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly rigorous.